# Ether Historical Prices

Tags: ether, history, economics

I am looking for historical datasets of the price of Ether. Similar to Bitcoin closing market price on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?showDataPoints=false&timespan=all&show_header=true&daysAverageString=1&scale=0&format=csv&address=) or [Coindesk OHLC dataset](http://www.coindesk.com/price/). Datasets in raw form are preferred (.json or .csv).  Where can I find such datasets?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/exchange#btc_eth) has a pretty complete dataset available.

[image: poloniex]

Raw data as [JSON here](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=14400). Edit the timestamps in the API to get a different snapshot. Edit the period to adjust the details.

Comment: Poloniex API is impressive, I will change this as my accepted answer because it also offers different currencyPairs to compare to as well as information about historical prices of other cryptocurrencies,

Comment: I really like the Raw data as JSON approach you used with Poloniex. Unfortunately I am not able to get the same information for the other exchange rates (BTC/USD for example). Can you maybe tell me how to access the JSON data online? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @AlexanderHempfing Normal, as BTC/USD is not quoted on Poloniex. You fund yourself in BTC, trading after other electronic currencies, but not fiat money.

Comment: @AlexanderHempfing BTC/USD is quoted on poloniex... instead of USD, you [put USDT in the url](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_BTC&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=14400)

Answer (score 13):

[Etherchain](https://www.etherchain.org/charts/)  and [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/charts) currently both allow you to download raw data for any of their charts.

Comment: yes, I was looking for the raw dataset, this is right on spot.

Comment: These links are all dead, is not possible to get the raw data anymore?