# eth subscribe logs not working

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

I want to get list of transactions by address and found example using web3.eth.subscribe. I wrote simple code from example

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'))

web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options, function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
    console.log(res)
})
.on("data", function(log){
    console.log(log)
})
.on("changed", function(log){
    console.log(log)
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

but i dont get nothing. No console info or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`web3.eth.subscribe` works for subscribing to `events`, which can be coded in a smart contract. In your code sample you are looking for events named `logs`, `error`, `changed` and `data`.

In order to get all the transactions of one address, you need a fully unpruned Ethereum node.

Possible Duplicate Question: [How to explore all transactions for a given account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8547/how-to-explore-all-transactions-for-a-given-account)