# How to get all the transactions made by a token address

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, external-api, rpc

Given the address of a token, how I can get all the transactions related to that address using JSON RPC or an external api such a api.etherscan.io?

The transactions that gives a Ethereum address are different that the transaction that gives an ERC20 token. Example:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496
https://etherscan.io/token/Aragon?a=0x9f7dd5ea934d188a599567ee104e97fa46cb4496

I need to get the two transaction that are registered for Aragon via API.

Comment: Or: [How to explore all transactions for a given account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8547/how-to-explore-all-transactions-for-a-given-account?rq=1)

Comment: Is not the same. See my edit, please.