# Ether Historical Price Data

Tags: ether, json-rpc, poloniex

I am looking for historical ether prices. There was a thread already discussing this [enter link description here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/635/ether-historical-prices/10742#10742), however, I would like to get not only the prices available for Ether on Poloniex but also for other VCs (e.g. BTC, LTC) to USD. In the end the web output should look like the output in the other thread. It looks like [this](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_%5C%20ETH&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=14400).
Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The link is https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=14400

Comment: And for USD: https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_ETH&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=14400

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the price tracking sites like [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) or [CryptoCompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/). They have aggregate data across various exchanges, multiple coins, multiple pairs, and historical data (for example, you can view ETH's historical data here: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no canonical ETH or BTC price, each exchange has its own.  Exchange may or may not collect historical data, and granularity of such data may be different.  Also, there are third-party aggregators that collect price data from exchanges and other sources and keep it.

So you basically has three options:

1. Ask exchanges and/or aggregators to shared historical price data with you, probably they will want you to pay for this data
2. Try to obtain desired data via public APIs of exchanges/aggregators (check [this](https://github.com/Alescontrela/coinmarketcap-history))
3. Try to parse desired data from Web pages of exchanges/aggregators