# Historical hourly or minute prices (API or bulk)

Tags: price

Questions to find ETH or other cryptocurrency historical prices have been asked and answered [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/cryptocurrency-historical-prices) or [there](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/635/ether-historical-prices). But I'm looking for **hourly** prices, or even less, for every **minute**, and for at least the past 4 weeks.

All APIs I have looked at offer either daily quotes, or fine-grained quotes but limited to the last 24 hours max.

So for the moment I'm collecting quotes from one of those APIs by running a `cron` job a few times a day, and I've collected 4-5 days worth of data, but this is cumbersome (need to aggregate them), unreliable (raspberry Pi 1B ain't high availability server) and, well, I have to wait to collect enough data.

***Question***: where could I find fine-grained quotes (1 per minute) for the last month, either REST API or a plain old internet link? Format does not matter.

Note: I consider republishing the info I'm collecting but I have to check first if this is compliant with the T&C - and it's probably not but worth a shot if the community finds it useful.

Comment: Poloniex gives you their historical BTC/ETH trading pair data over API

Comment: Can you confirm the hour or even minute granularity beyond 24h?

Comment: Poloniex's granularity is only down to 5 minutes (300 seconds) according to their public APIs here: https://poloniex.com/support/api/
Refer to : returnChartData

Comment: Ever find a solution for minute by minute? Coindesk used to offer this but it seems that they have stopped.